# Comparing symbolic mathematical expressions with Python using Sympy

Tags: python, sympy, symbolic-math

I would like to check which mathematical expressions are equal.
I want to do this using Python I tried it with Sympy.

My idea was to use simplify in order to reduce the expressions such that a pair that is equal will be reduced to the same expression.
Then I substract them all with each other in my two for loops and check if the result equals to zero.

Unfortunately no substraction results in zero which is very improbable to be correct.
I think that probably the simplify function does not really do what I need.
Is there a function in sympy to check if two expressions are indeed mathematically equal?

This is my code so far:

```
from sympy import *

a = symbols ('a')
b = symbols ('b')
n = symbols ('n')
m = symbols ('m')

x1=simplify(log(a,n**(log(b,a))))
x2=simplify(((a**n)/(b**m))**(1/b))
x3=simplify(b**(n*log(a)))
x4=simplify(log(b,n))
x5=simplify(a**((n-m)/b))
x6=simplify(n*(log(a)+log(b)))
x7=simplify(log((a**n)*(b**n)))
x8=simplify(a**(log(b**n)))

L=[x1,x2,x3,x4,x5,x6,x7,x8]



for i in range (0 , 6):

    for k in range (i+1 , 7):

        print(L[i]-L[k])
```

Comment: Are any of those expressions actually equal? I don't see any that are.

Comment: There should be some that are equal mathematically by performing various transformation e.g. base shifting etc.

Answer (score 1):

The `a.equals(b)` method will try really hard (including using random values for variables) to show that `a == b`. But be aware that two expressions might only be equal for a given range of values. So it might be better to indicate that your symbols are, for example, `positive` or `integer` as in `Symbol('n', integer=True)` or `Symbol('a', positive=True)`. If you do that then `simplify(a - b)` will more likely reduce to 0 as will `a.equals(b)`.

`posify` is a function which can replace symbols with symbols having positive assumptions; see below how x6 and x7 simplify when symbols are positive:

```
>>> from sympy import posify
>>> dif = x6 - x7
>>> dif.simplify() == 0
Ealse
>>> posify(dif)[0].simplify()  # [0] gets the the positive-symbol expression
```

You can also make numerical substitutions yourself using `x._random(lo,LO,hi,HI)` where `(lo, hi)` are the lower and upper limit for the real part of the number and `(LO, HI)` are the same for the imaginary part, e.g. `x._random(0,0,1,0)` will give a random value that is real between 0 and 1. Create a replacement dictionary and replace the values and check the absolute value of the difference in `a` and `b`. Something like this (using the loop as you presented it above):

```
for i in range (0 , 6):
  for k in range (i+1 , 7):
    v = L[i]-(L[k])
    reps = {i: i._random(0,0,1,0) for i in v.free_symbols}
    v = v.xreplace(reps).n()
    if abs(v) < 1e-9:
      print(L[i],L[k],abs(v))
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way to check if functions are equal would be to evaluate them at maybe a few thousand points and check the outputs.

```
from sympy import *

def generateOutput(L, x):
    # x -> list of points to evaluate functions at (maybe randomly generated?)
    # L -> input list of functions
    # returns list of outputs of L[i] applied to x



a = symbols ('a')
b = symbols ('b')
n = symbols ('n')
m = symbols ('m')

x1=simplify(log(a,n**(log(b,a))))
x2=simplify(((a**n)/(b**m))**(1/b))
x3=simplify(b**(n*log(a)))
x4=simplify(log(b,n))
x5=simplify(a**((n-m)/b))
x6=simplify(n*(log(a)+log(b)))
x7=simplify(log((a**n)*(b**n)))
x8=simplify(a**(log(b**n)))

L=[x1,x2,x3,x4,x5,x6,x7,x8]

outputs = generateOutput(L)
# Compare outputs
```

Comment: Thank you for the idea! This would indeed simplify the task. Using a lot of randomly generated arguments for the functions should provide enough accuracy to check them against each other

Answer (score 0):

[From the docs](http://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/core.html?#sympy.core.relational.Equality):

The `Eq` function (from `sympy.core.relational`) looks like it is what you want. Note that if it is given more complex arguments, you will have to `simplify` to get a result (see last code example in link).

Note: Those for loops don't look right. The first one will only go through indices 0-5 and the second only through i+1 to 6, so the last item in the list will be skipped completely.

Comment: Thank you, I will try to make it work with Eq! Concerning the note, I am not sure if I get the point. As far as my understanding goes I think the first for loop iterates from  0 to 6 (eg x1 to x7) and the second one from i+1 to 7. The last element in the list should only occur in the second loop. This is an effect of the prevention of double counting. Do I get the indexation wrong in Python/in the foor loop?

Comment: `range` is not inclusive on the second argument (ie. `range(3) == [0,1,2]`)